# Creating folder using Google Drive API gives invalid_grant but can create actual file with same connection

Tags: c#, google-drive-api

I can setup a Google user content connection with Google API and can get folders and even upload/create files to folders. But the same connection used to create a new regular folder anywhere gives the error invalid_grant with no further information. I am passing in a valid `folderId` to set as parent. I have tried different scopes and a long shot of syncing my clock like I have seen on other solutions. I can't seem to figure out the issue. Anyone else have seen this?

Here is code that works to upload a file to a folder:

```
    public async Task<string> Upload(string localFilePath, string folderId, string fileName, string refreshToken, string userId)
    {
        var file = new File();
        file.MimeType = GetMimeType(localFilePath);
        file.Name = fileName;
        file.Parents = new List<string> { folderId };

        var driveService = await GetDriveService(refreshToken, userId);

        // File's content.
        var byteArray = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(localFilePath);
        var stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream(byteArray);
        var request = driveService.Files.Create(file, stream, file.MimeType);
        await request.UploadAsync();
        return request.ResponseBody.Id;
    }
```

Here is what I've been trying in creating a folder:

```
    public async Task<string> CreateFolder(string folderId, string folderName, string refreshToken, string userId)
    {
        var newFolderId = string.Empty;
        var driveService = await GetDriveService(refreshToken, userId);

        FilesResource.ListRequest list = driveService.Files.List();

        var file = new File();
        file.MimeType = "application/vnd.google-apps.folder";
        file.Name = folderName;
        file.Parents = new List<string> { folderId };

        var request = driveService.Files.Create(file);
        request.Fields = "Id";
        var newFolder = await request.ExecuteAsync();
        return newFolder.Id;
    }
```

And, here is the method in defining `driveService`:

```
    private async Task<DriveService> GetDriveService(string refreshToken, string userId)
    {
        var credential = await GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
            clientSecrets: new ClientSecrets { ClientId = "xyz.apps.googleusercontent.com", ClientSecret = "xyz" },
            scopes: new string[] { DriveService.Scope.Drive, DriveService.Scope.DriveFile },
            dataStore: new MemoryDataStore(userId, refreshToken),
            user: userId,
            taskCancellationToken: CancellationToken.None);

        var driveService = new DriveService(new BaseClientService.Initializer
        {
            HttpClientInitializer = credential,
            ApplicationName = "XYZ"
        });
        return driveService;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in [creating a folder](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/folder#creating_a_folder),

> In the Drive API, a folder is essentially a file — one identified by the special folder MIME type `application/vnd.google-apps.folder`. You can create a new folder by inserting a file with this MIME type and a folder title. Do not include an extension when setting a folder title.

Please try using the given code:

```
File fileMetadata = new File();
fileMetadata.setName("Invoices");
fileMetadata.setMimeType("application/vnd.google-apps.folder");

File file = driveService.files().create(fileMetadata)
        .setFields("id")
        .execute();
System.out.println("Folder ID: " + file.getId());
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply, but this is exactly what I am doing including setting the mimetype. Actually the link you provided for api v3 is same as my code above in the second code block (this is where I got the example). So this does not resolve the invalid_grant issue which seems like a permission issue which is very odd if I can upload a file with the same credentials.

Comment: Also, here is the response and error only for CreateFolder:

Error:"invalid_grant", Description:"", Uri:""
   at Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.Flows.AuthorizationCodeFlow.<FetchTokenAsync>d__35.MoveNext() in C:\Apiary\v1_19\google-api-dotnet-client\Src\Support\GoogleApis.Auth\OAuth2\Flows\AuthorizationCodeFlow.cs:line 317

Answer (score 0):

I apologize, I am a victim of a copy/paste or fat finger error that I just did not notice unfortunately until now. I am managing multiple cloud connections in this app for similar purposes, and at the beginning of the call in this case to create folder I either copy/pasted or fat fingered an enum value that was improperly requesting to get the saved refreshtoken from a different cloud provider ala one drive or dropbox. Once switched to pull the saved google refreshtoken, it works. Well, at least there is a working example of create folder and upload file above :-) Btw, the line request.Fields = "Id"; needs to be request.Fields = "id"; where id needs to be lower case...otherwise a different error pops up saying the field is invalid. Thanks.